# High ping inquiry

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ping

I have a network of 50+ clients and the average ping = 10ms/50ms!

Days ago I noticed that the ping was quite high after one of my clients' CPE was connected to the AP!

So my question is: If one of my clients has a high ping due to a faulty cable or bad signal, does it affect the entire network? Would the rest of the clients have a high ping as well?

Comment: Are the ping packets big enough to effect the network?

Comment: Pinging with 32 Bytes of Data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem by isolating the ethernet ports!

Comment: Sounds like you may have had a loop / [broadcast storm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_radiation)

Comment: I think it was a very high amount of broadcast/multicast traffic on the network!

Comment: a.k.a Broadcast storm - caused by a loop in your network?

Comment: Most probably a DoS attack!

Comment: No, probably not. Unless you have malicious users or have connected your network directly to the internet.

Comment: My bet is on the malicious users! some of them were using server stress tools, I had to limit the input connections as well.

Answer (score 0):

In order to properly answer this question, the network needs to be better described.   PING can tell things about the network, but what it tells depends on the way the devices are connected, where they are pinging to and the configuration of the routers.

Assuming this is a wide area WIFI type connection (which the statement my clients' CPE has connected to the AP) may imply, this most likely means that the client is making heavy use of the available bandwidth.  Pings of 10ms with 40ms jitter are not that bad for a public-spectrum WIFI network as you can't control what other parties are doing - but, of-course, this depends somewhat on the speed of the links.

It could reflect a bad cable but this is unlikely (if its a bad cable its still passing traffic, but with degraded performance).  It could be a bad signal, but more likely its due to WIFI noise if its on a WIFI network.  If its on a WIFI network it could affect other clients - but really anything could because its utlising a limited amount of bandwidth between more users.

Comment: I have a mikrotik router configured as a DHCP server-hotspot and Ubiquiti Rocket M2 configured as an AP+WDS in bridge mode. After I disconnect that specific client, ping immediately returns to normal! and as soon as the client reconnects the problem reoccurs.

Comment: Then the problem is that the client is saturating the available bandwidth and causing latencies to increase.

Comment: If by saturating you mean consuming the available bandwidth. then it's not the problem! because I'm using traffic shaping (Rate limiting). Do you think a defective ethernet cable can cause the problem from the client's end?

Comment: When you discover that the problem is the amount of data being used relative to the available capacity on the link, please come back and accept my answer !  (I wonder if you are shaping the traffic before it traverses the WIFI network, and how many simultaneous connections that user is opening)